# what should I use to create a QGraphicsView overlay that encapsulates QMimeData in Qt and C++?

Tags: c++, qt

I want to create an overlay for graphics view. Currently I'm using `QDrag` which encapsulates mime data using the `setMimeData()` method, and I can set a QPixmap that follows the mouse pointer when I drag it.

The problem is that I have to hold down the left mouse button for it to work. Now the user hits a button, she has to hold the left button to drag the graph to the desired area and release the button. In practice, it is very non-intuitive.

I want to make it the case that the user clicks on a button and releases the mouse button, then the graph follows the mouse pointer to where the user wants to place it, then she clicks the mouse again and the graph gets placed there. However, as a beginner in Qt, I don't know which class I can use to accomplish that.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `QGraphicsItem` when a mouse click happens on the scene, then simply move it around while tracking the mouse.